# Issues with Dates in Apache OpenNLP

Tags: apache, text-mining, opennlp, data-extraction

For a recent project to aid me learning NLP I am working on a number of documents, each of which contain a date. What I would like to be able to do is read the unstructured data and identify the date or dates within, converting it into a numeric format and possibly setting it to the documents metadata. (Note: Since the documents being used is all pseudo information, the actual meta data of the files being read in are false).

Recently I have been attempting to use OpenNLP in conjunction with Lucene to do so and it works to a given degree.
However if the date is written as "13 January 1990" or "2010/01/05", OpenNLP only identifies "January 1990" and "2010" respectively, but not the entire date.  Other date formats may have issues as well, I have yet to try them all.  While I recognise that OpenNLP works upon a statistical basis rather than a format basis, I can't help but get the feeling I'm making an elementary mistake.

Am I making a mistake?  If not is there an easy manner in which to rectify this?

I understand that I may be able to construct my own trained model based on a training data set.  Is the Apache OpenNLP one freely available, so I may extend it? Are there any others that are freely available?

Is there a better way to do this?  I've heard of Apache UIMA, the main reason why I went for OpenNLP is due to its mention in Taming Text by Manning.  I should note that the extraction of dates is the first stage of the project and other data will be extracted later as well.

Many thanks for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in OpenNLP but I know that the problem you are trying to solve is called Temporal Expression Extraction (because I do research in this field :P). Nowadays, there are some systems which can greatly help you in extracting and unambiguously representing the temporal meaning of such expressions.

Here are some references:

1. ManTIME, [online demo](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~filannim/projects/tempeval-3/), [software](https://github.com/filannim/ManTIME/)
2. HeidelTime, [online demo](http://heideltime.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/heideltime/), [software](https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime/releases)
3. SUTime, [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/), [software](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml)

If you want a broader overview of the field, please have a look at the results of the last temporal information extraction challenge ([TempEval-3, Task A](http://derczynski.com/sheffield/papers/tempeval-3.pdf)).

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll check out the packages later.  I currently got around it by checking the tokens before and after any 1 or 2 length dates and then have converted it to a standard date format, but my current system makes a number of assumptions with regards to the formatting of some dates.

Comment: If you are searching for a temporal normaliser in Python than you can have a look at NorMA (https://github.com/filannim/timex-normaliser). A temporal normaliser takes a temporal expression (e.g. '5th of May, 2014') and returns its ISO-8601 representation (e.g. '05-05-2014').